# Get Scala Type for a java.lang.Class[T] in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-java-interop

I was looking at [the scala reflection overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) and I'm wondering if it is possible to use a `java.lang.Class<T>` as a Type in Scala 2.10.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }

class Reflector {
  def getType: ru.Type = {
    ru.typeOf[java.lang.String]
  }
  def getType[T](clazz: Class[T]): ru.Type = {
    //is it possible to implement me?
  }
}
```

Is it possible to implement the `parse[T](clazz: Class[T]): ru.Type` method without changing its signature in order to be able to call it from java with `new Reflector().parse(String.class)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could implement your method like this:

```
def getType[T](clazz: Class[T])(implicit runtimeMirror: ru.Mirror) =
  runtimeMirror.classSymbol(clazz).toType
```

And then call it like this:

```
implicit val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
getType(classOf[String])
```

You might be interested in the [smirror library](https://github.com/fwbrasil/smirror) as it contains a similar method

```
def sClassOf[T](clazz: Class[T])(implicit runtimeMirror: Mirror): SClass[T]
```

Where `SClass` contains a `typ` property.

---

### Edit

You might want to change the method to this (that would keep the same signature)

```
def getType[T](clazz: Class[T]):ru.Type = {
  val runtimeMirror =  ru.runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)
  runtimeMirror.classSymbol(clazz).toType
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to comply with the 'without changing its signature' requirement of the OP